# How to write text on image in windows phone 8?

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, photos

I have a image and i want write text on it. After write text on image , i want move text to everywhere on screen where i like. I tried write text on image but i just can write on screen and i can't move it. Can you help me. Thank All :))
And this is my code :

```
WriteableBitmap wb;
wb = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)ImgZoom.Source);
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = Txt.Text;
tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
tb.FontSize = 70;
tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
wb.Render(tb, new TranslateTransform() { X = 25, Y = 191 });
wb.Invalidate();
```

Comment: Well then you have re-render that WriteableBitmap with a new X, Y location for the TextBlock.  A Bitmap is static, consider it like a backbuffer, it won't change until your rewrite over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one image and you want to write text on it and then move text to everywhere. Then hope so this code will help you.

```
Xaml : 

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image Source="/Images/3.png" />
    </Grid>


C# : 
    private TranslateTransform move = new TranslateTransform();
    private TransformGroup rectangleTransforms = new TransformGroup();

    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = "Hello..!";
        tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        tb.FontSize = 70;
        tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(tb);

        rectangleTransforms.Children.Add(move);

        tb.RenderTransform = rectangleTransforms;

        tb.ManipulationStarted +=
            new EventHandler<ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(Rectangle_ManipulationStarted);
        tb.ManipulationDelta +=
            new EventHandler<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(Rectangle_ManipulationDelta);
        tb.ManipulationCompleted +=
            new EventHandler<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(Rectangle_ManipulationCompleted);
    }
    void Rectangle_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
       //your code
    }
    void Rectangle_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        // Move the Textbox.
        move.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
        move.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;


    }
    void Rectangle_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //your code
    }
```

For more about this code please refer this link [manipulation events for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff426933(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Ok thank you, it work very good. Now i want save image in local photos. and how to save? Can you help me?

Comment: just read this link hope so it will help to you 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394006(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Oh i have a problem, i want move text in image, Can you limit text move only in image?

Answer (score 1):

Hi try also this to move only in image boundary

```
C# : 
    int trX = 0;
    int trY = 0;
    TextBlock croppingRectangle;

    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        init();
    }
    public void init()
    {


        TextBlock rect = new TextBlock();
        rect.Text = "Hello......Hello......";

        rect.Height = 94;  //fixed 
        rect.MaxHeight = image1.Height;
        rect.MaxWidth = image1.Width;
        rect.Width = 300; //fixed
        rect.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        rect.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        rect.FontSize = 70;
        rect.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        rect.Margin = image1.Margin;
        rect.ManipulationDelta += new EventHandler<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(rect_ManipulationDelta);

        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(rect);
        LayoutRoot.Height = image1.Height;
        LayoutRoot.Width = image1.Width;
    }
    private void rect_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        GeneralTransform gt = ((TextBlock)sender).TransformToVisual(LayoutRoot);
        Point p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        int intermediateValueY = (int)((LayoutRoot.Height - ((TextBlock)sender).Height));
        int intermediateValueX = (int)((LayoutRoot.Width - ((TextBlock)sender).Width));
        croppingRectangle = (TextBlock)sender;
        TranslateTransform tr = new TranslateTransform();
        trX += (int)e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
        trY += (int)e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
        if (trY < (-intermediateValueY / 2))
        {
            trY = (-intermediateValueY / 2);
        }
        else if (trY > (intermediateValueY / 2))
        {
            trY = (intermediateValueY / 2);
        }

        if (trX < (-intermediateValueX / 2))
        {
            trX = (-intermediateValueX / 2);
        }
        else if (trX > (intermediateValueX / 2))
        {
            trX = (intermediateValueX / 2);
        }

        tr.X = trX;
        tr.Y = trY;

        croppingRectangle.RenderTransform = tr;
    }
```

XAML :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <Image Width="300" Height="300" x:Name="image1" Source="/Images/3.png" Stretch="Fill"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I tried but not true. [link1](http://upanh123.com/image/TKz) [link2](http://upanh123.com/image/TKQ). This is 2 link before i call init() and after call init().

Comment: [C#](http://www.paste.org/76224) and [XAML](http://www.paste.org/76225) this is fullpage its working fine in my side plz check it again or please share your code to me.Thank you

Comment: Plz remove margin from image control or try this one

 <Grid Background="Red"> <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF69CFC5"> <Image Stretch="Fill" x:Name="image1" Width="300" Height="300" Source="/Assets/fan.jpg" /> <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="178,538,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/> </Grid> </Grid>

Answer (score 1):

XAML :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF69CFC5">
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Image Stretch="Fill" x:Name="image1" Width="300" Height="300" Source="/Assets/fan.jpg" Margin="10,0,-10,176"/>
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="178,538,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>           
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

C#:

```
  int trX = 0;
        int trY = 0;
        TextBlock croppingRectangle;

    public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //init();      
    }
    public void init()
    {
        TextBlock rect = new TextBlock();
        rect.Text = "Hello......Hello......";

        rect.Height = 94;  //fixed 
        rect.MaxHeight = image1.Height;
        rect.MaxWidth = image1.Width;
        rect.Width = 300; //fixed
        rect.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        rect.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        rect.FontSize = 70;
        rect.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        rect.Margin = image1.Margin;
        rect.ManipulationDelta += new EventHandler<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(rect_ManipulationDelta);

        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(rect);
        LayoutRoot.Height = image1.Height;
        LayoutRoot.Width = image1.Width;
    }
    private void rect_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        GeneralTransform gt = ((TextBlock)sender).TransformToVisual(LayoutRoot);
        Point p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        int intermediateValueY = (int)((LayoutRoot.Height - ((TextBlock)sender).Height));
        int intermediateValueX = (int)((LayoutRoot.Width - ((TextBlock)sender).Width));
        croppingRectangle = (TextBlock)sender;
        TranslateTransform tr = new TranslateTransform();
        trX += (int)e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
        trY += (int)e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
        if (trY < (-intermediateValueY / 2))
        {
            trY = (-intermediateValueY / 2);
        }
        else if (trY > (intermediateValueY / 2))
        {
            trY = (intermediateValueY / 2);
        }

        if (trX < (-intermediateValueX / 2))
        {
            trX = (-intermediateValueX / 2);
        }
        else if (trX > (intermediateValueX / 2))
        {
            trX = (intermediateValueX / 2);
        }

        tr.X = trX;
        tr.Y = trY;

        croppingRectangle.RenderTransform = tr;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        init();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Plz remove margin from image control  or try this one

<Grid Background="Red">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF69CFC5">

            <Image Stretch="Fill" x:Name="image1" Width="300" Height="300" Source="/Assets/fan.jpg" />
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="178,538,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>